# Using ShowTypingMiddleware to display typing indicator not working

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to use the provided `ShowTypingMiddleware` Class to automatically display a typing indicator on every turn. After attaching it correctly to the middleware collection still, nothing happens.

Tried with parameters, without parameters.

```
const adapter: BotFrameworkAdapter = this.createBotFrameworkAdapter();
adapter.use(new ShowTypingMiddleware());
```

As mentioned in several docs, the attachment to the collection with .use() should be all to comfortably enable typing indication. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What channel are you using? Your configuration looks fine.

Comment: Is this the V3 or V4 BotFramework?

Comment: From the code snippets, it looks like he is using v4.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you so much for your response. Yes i am using v4. I am using the Bot-Framework-Emulator as Channel. This should be fine right?

Comment: What version of the emulator are you using? It seems to be working alright in v4.5.

Comment: Hi @tdurnford, I used 4.4.1 but just updated to 4.5 and still no effect. Very strange!

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? It was working fine for me in v4.5.0, but I just updated to v4.5.3 and it's no longer working for me.

Comment: @ tdurnford, I am also using v4.5.3. Did you already test if a downgrade does restore the functionality?